# List all regex matches, one per line of output

Tags: linux, cygwin, regex

I know that I can find regex matches using `egrep`.

My need is a bit more esoteric:

I need to list all regex matches, one per line of output.

So, assume a file containing the following:

```
This is just some sample 1text to illustrate the 2text seeker I had in mind.
As you can see in this 3text, I have many 4text matches, more than one 5text match per line of 6text.
```

With a regex of /`[0-9]+text`/, I want the output to be:

```
1text
2text
3text
4text
5text
6text
```

Short of cobbling up a program to do just that, is there any way I can generate the wanted output using standard commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`egrep -o '[0-9]+text' filename`

From the egrep man page:

> `-o, --only-matching`
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Comment: Oh. My. Gosh. How could I missed that?! Thanks!